# Where to store API KEY in j2me?

Tags: java-me, api-key

in my project, I am calling webservice with http get request.
API key is also there in http get parameter.
in j2me devices before connecting to the internet it is showing the URL and asking for permission to user.Here user can easily see my api key.

and i don't want to store api key in my application also.because using decompiler
anybody can get api key from applciation.

So my question is where to store api key and how to use it for calling web services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the API key is required to use the webservice, then you MUST store it somewhere in your app...By the way, you can store it in some kind of an encrypted way, so a simple decompile does not reveal it.

If the user should enter the API key, the you can store it in the standard RMS store outside of your app, again maybe encrypted.

An for the URL issue, use HTTP POST request instead of HTTP GET, and send the key in the post data.

Comment: http post is not supported by that api.
i am thinking to send send a http post to my web server, my web server will send http get to api server and return to my app. Is there any other way??

Comment: using a proxy like that seems reasonable, that way you can even do some kind of preprocessing of the result in the (much powerful) proxy server instead of the j2me app

Comment: I don't know if that would work, but you can try URLEncoding the API key in the GET request. The lots of %3F's and stuff can hide the key for the first look (and it doesn't fit in the screen, too:))

Comment: In that case i think i should store api key on the server it self?

Comment: @buc "some kind of an encrypted way" - what do you mean by that? wouldn't the decompiled source reveal the "encryption way"?

Answer (score 0):

You could encrypt the api key and store it as you do just now and then POST it to the web service.